# Question about continuity at point $(a,b)$, contradicting book example

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity, piecewise-continuity

I included example 6 as a context for examples building up but the main concern with my question is examples 7 and 8 from Stewart's Calculus, the 8th edition.

Example 7's rationale is that although with the piecewise representation, the function $g(x,y)$ is defined at $(0,0)$, it is still discontinuous because the limit at that point which approaches $(0/0)$ does not exist.

However, in example 8, a function of similar nature is shown. Yet again the function $f(x,y)$ is defined explicitly at point $(0,0)$ by the piecewise representation. Yet this time the author goes to take the limit of the function and arrives at the conclusion that the $limit$ of $(f,x)$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ is $0$ and **defined**.

Don't have high enough reputation so link to image is here: [https://i.gyazo.com/87f2e2e625c5f2cc25cdb041f8015eba.png)](https://i.gyazo.com/87f2e2e625c5f2cc25cdb041f8015eba.png)

I don't understand how this is logical? I see that the $limit$ for $(x,y)$ would result in yet another $0/0$ fraction which would mean it is discontinuous because that limit does not exist. Can anyone care to explain?

Comment: Do you understand why $\lim_\limits{x\to 1}\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ exists and is equal to $2$ even though the numerator and denominator of the fraction both approach $0$ as $x\to 1$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Looks like the use of L'Hopitals Differentiation rule no? The limit of the ratio of 1st derivatives?

Comment: L’Hospital’s rule is overkill: $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=x+1$ for all $x$ for which both are defined. But my real point here is that the $\frac00$ fraction tells you nothing about whether the limit exists: that depends entirely on the function. In Example 7 we find that the limit as we approach the origin along the $x$-axis is $1$, while the limit as we approach the origin along the $y$-axis is $-1$; since the two are different, the function has no limit at the origin. In Example 8, on the other hand, we can prove that the limit is $0$ no matter how we approach the origin.

Comment: I don't follow the first equality, not sure how to arrive at x+1 representation. Any resource to read up about that? I'm in a multivariate class and a bit rusty on Calculus 1 and 2(been 2-3 years). I understand the 0/0 or infinity/infinity is not a determinable form and we must use other methods to evaluate the limit. The notion of proving a limit by looking at every approach is still something I am trying to understand. How to solve for every approach without brute force?

Comment: It’s just factoring: $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$, so $$\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{x-1}=\frac{x-1}{x-1}\cdot(x+1)=x+1$$ at every point except $x=-1$, where the lefthand side is undefined.

Comment: If you can find two different paths that result in different limits, there’s no need to look further. If the limit **does** exist, it can be difficult to find a proof; presumably Example 4 shows how this can be done for the function in Example 8.

Comment: Ah thank you for showing the factorization, I can't believe I was not able to see that. You are correct, I did not notice the limit had been proven in example 4 with an epsilon/delta proof which goes a bit over my head. Thank you for the help

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer but I wanted to show you this image to show why $f$ is continuous and $g$ is not:

[image: graph continuity]

Here $g(x,y)$ is the larger red curve and $f(x,y)$ is the lower blue curve. For this image, $y=0.1$

As you see, $f$ is continuous meanwhile $g$ has a discontinuity at $x=0$. As $x$ approaches $0$, $g$ approaches $-1$, however $g(0,0)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the visualization, visually it makes sense but I was attempting to understand this with algebraic manipulation. It still helps though to see this!